# Does this hold true

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Let $f$ be function such as

$f(x)=g(x)$ when $x\in Q$

$f(x)=h(x)$ when $x\in R/Q$

$f$ is continious at $x'$ iff $g(x')=h(x')$

Does this hold true and if so, why?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Not much really, first time seeing this. I asked here something like this : if for example f(x) = sinx x, when x is from Q  and f(x)=cos x if its not, since for pi/4  sinx=cosx and that is equal to left and right limit of both rational and irrational sequence when x approaches pi/4 can I assume that f is continuous at pi/4 without epsilon delta proof? Somebody proposed this lemma but I can't proove it. I'm only starting to do calculus /analysis for the first time now.

Comment: Are you making any continuity assumptions on $g$ and $h$?

Comment: He seemed to imply that continuity of g and h is irrelevant. Also I edited my first comment

Comment: Thanks , few  more questions if you don't mind - is my original statement about assuming continuity without epsilon delta proof true? And does this lemma  hold true if g and h are continious

Comment: Yo can use sequential continuity; it is not necsssary to use an $\epsilon -\delta $ proof unless you are specifically asked for it. I have edited my answer to cover the case when $g$ and $h$ are continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False. Let $g$ be  a function which is not continuous at any point and  $h=g$. Then $g(x')=h(x')$ holds for all $x'$ but $f$ is not continuous at any point $x'$.

However, if $g$ and $h$ are continuous then the result is true: Suppose $g(x') \neq h(x')$. Take a sequence of rational numbers $x_n$ tending to $x'$.  Then $f(x_n)=g(x_n) \to g(x')$ and $f(x_n+\frac {\sqrt 2} n) =h(x_n+\frac {\sqrt 2} n)\to h(x')$. This proves that $f$ is not continuous at $x'$. On the other hand if $g(x')=h(x')$ , $x_n \to x'$ and $y_n \to x'$ with each $x_n$ rational and each $y_n$ irrational then $\lim f(x_n) =g(x')=h(x')=\lim f(y_n)$. This is enough to conclude that $f$ is continuous at $x'$.